# TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable while using decorators inside classes

Tags: python, class, error-handling, static-methods, python-decorators

I have some code below

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,height,weight)
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

    @staticmethod
    def some_op(func)
        def inner(*args,**kwargs)
        s = func(*args,**kwargs)
        print("Implementing function...")


    @some_op
    def num_op(self,values):
        for value in values:
            v = value * 10
            q = v - 100
            c = q ** -1
        return c

example = Example()

values = [11,23123,1209,234]

example.num_op(values)
```

But it outputs:

```
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

I don't really know decorators inside a class, so how should I change the code so that it returns:

```
Implementing function...
0.0004464285714285714
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static method isn't callable; it's an object whose `__get__` method returns a callable object. However, you aren't accessing `some_op` (incomplete definition aside) as an attribute, but as a regular function, so its `__get__` method never gets used. You have two options:

1. Define `some_op` as a regular function outside the class.
2. Don't define `some_op` as a static method. Since you are only calling it inside the class definition itself, let it be a regular function, and just don't use it as an instance method. (You can define it as `_some_op` to emphasize that it shouldn't be used outside the class.)

For more information on what `__get__` is and how it works, see the [Decriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and the section on [static methods](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods) in particular.